# bootstrap modalInstance is not closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an angular app that is using modals from bootstrap. Maybe this is a silly error but I can't find it. I have a button which must store some information in the controller and after that close the modal. The problem that I'm facing is that I can't close the modal when I store this info. What can be the problem? This is the code.

```
self.runAction = function(infoToSave) {
    for(var i=0; i < infoToSave.length; i++) {
        self.actionsToSave.push(infoToSave[i]);
    }
    self.$uibModalInstance.close();
}
```